# How to fix "http not found in com.apple.developer.associated-domains entitlement" in iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7

I have created a basic iOS app in Swift that uses a WKWebView. I am using `SecAddSharedWebCredential` and `SecRequestSharedWebCredential` to save and load usernames and passwords within the users KeyChain.

When I launch the app with the simulator, everything works perfectly fine. Although, when I launch on a device, I get the error of:

```
http not found in com.apple.developer.associated-domains entitlement
```

Within the simulator and device, when displaying the credential list to a user, it comes up as (note the `http`):

[image]

When using my save and get functions, I make sure that I pass in my URL, so I don't think that could be the problem.

```
SecAddSharedWebCredential(self.URLPath, loginUsername, loginPassword)
SecRequestSharedWebCredential(self.URLPath, nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have something like **webcredentials:http://example.com** in your entitlements. Try getting rid of the http so it's just **webcredentials:example.com**.